# Navbar dropdown disappearing on hover

Tags: jquery, css

On the right side of the navbar when you click on "Sign In", it spawns the dropdown with the login box, etc. However, when you hover over with your mouse it disappears after a second.

I can't figure out what's causing that or even if it's CSS based...

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
_showSubMenu = function(elem, elemID, options, menu, e) {
  var menuItem = $(e.currentTarget).find('> a');
  var subMenu = menuItem.next('.ipsMenu');
  $(e.currentTarget).on('mouseleave', _.bind(_hideSubMenu, this, elem, elemID, options, menu));
  var itemPosition = ips.utils.position.getElemPosition(menuItem);
  var itemSize = ips.utils.position.getElemDims(menuItem);
  var subMenuSize = ips.utils.position.getElemDims(subMenu);
  if ($('html').attr('dir') == 'rtl') {
    var right = (itemSize.outerWidth - 5);
    if ((itemPosition.viewportOffset.right + itemSize.outerWidth + subMenuSize.outerWidth - 5) > $(window).width()) {
      if ((itemPosition.viewportOffset.right + 5 - subMenuSize.outerWidth) >= 0) {
        right = ((subMenuSize.outerWidth * -1) + 5);
      }
    }
    subMenu.css({
      right: right + 'px',
      top: (menuItem.position()['top'] - 5) + 'px'
    }).show();
  } else {
    var left = (itemSize.outerWidth - 5);
    if ((itemPosition.viewportOffset.left + itemSize.outerWidth + subMenuSize.outerWidth - 5) > $(window).width()) {
      if ((itemPosition.viewportOffset.left + 5 - subMenuSize.outerWidth) >= 0) {
        left = ((subMenuSize.outerWidth * -1) + 5);
      }
    }
    subMenu.css({
      left: left + 'px',
      top: (menuItem.position()['top'] - 5) + 'px'
    }).show();
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it better if you provide some codes to support your question

Comment: What does the following line does? `$(e.currentTarget).on('mouseleave', _.bind(_hideSubMenu, this, elem, elemID, options, menu));`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is CSS based. I would avoid using a CSS hover to create that functionality (as it requires your mouse to stay on the button, or to add some css that adds to it)... instead I recommend using jQuery's toggle feature:

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp

Something like:

```
$("#signIn").click(function(){
    $("loginDiv").toggle();
});
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response! Unfortunately I've never used jQuery before so I wouldn't know where to start or put that or what I need to edit/remove from the current CSS. Do you know what of the CSS being used now is causing it so I can just modify/remove it?

Comment: it's an inline declaration to the elUserSignIn_menu element. You need to use javascript/jquery to make it work better. Change the display:none; to display:block; ...also jQuery is dead simple... should take you 5 mins to learn the basics... well worth it!

Comment: After some digging I found some jQuery it appears to be using... I don't think CSS is causing the disappearing menu. All I did was copy/paste the code from the header into the navbar and I think the jquery is being used to disappear based on where on the page it is..